# Magento Product edit - Quantity getting increased automatically upon saving product

Tags: php, magento

I am facing the same kind of issue on one of the Magento sites we are working on. Its Magento 1.6.2 for us.

Sometimes what happens is, there is simple product, its qty is set to 0. In admin, when I make the qty to 1 and save the product, the product is getting saved ans showing the success message twice. Ans also increased qty 2 instead of 1. Not sure why this is happenning and strange thing is, it happens only sometime, not always. Mostly its working fine. Only few times that problem occur.

Comment: Did You make any type of customization in code?? if yes then comment it out then check

Comment: may be the product `save()` function is called twice.

Comment: @SumitNeema we did not do such code change yet, also its happening only few times, not always. But we dont know under what circumstances it happens.